# material-ui@next without withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to make a project on `material-ui@next`, but I do not want to use `withStyles`. But the draft `TypeScript` in which the decorator `@withStyles` doesn't want to coexist.So the question arises - can the `material-ui@next` use without resorting to `withStyles`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Material UI without `withStyle()`, [as described in their documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order).

If you try adding a className to a Material UI component (given that style is imported like `import ./style.css`), that style might get overridden by the Material UI style by default due to CSS injection order.

If you look at the `<head>` of your application HTML during run-time in the browser, you may notice any custom CSS styles you may have imported may appear **before** any Material UI styles. When they do, the later defined styles will take precedence and negate your custom ones.

One way to fix that is add an HTML comment like `<!-- jss-insertion-point -->` to the bottom of your `<head>` so that JSS (which is used by Material UI) knows where to properly inject the `<link>` tags.

With that, enclose your app component in a `JssProvider` in your entry-point JavaScript file like so:

```
<JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
  <YourAppGoesHere />
</JssProvider>
```

The variables used in the props above are defined as such:

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { create } from 'jss';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from 'material-ui-next/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
const jss = create(jssPreset());
jss.options.insertionPoint = 'jss-insertion-point';
```

After doing the above, Material UI styles will come first, followed by your custom styles afterward. That way, your custom styles will always take precendence over the Material UI ones.

Comment: For those using Create React App, you'll need to [follow the "Other HTML Element" instructions here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#other-html-element) which require you to set a `noscript` object instead of a comment — as CRA strips public/index.html of comments — and modify the jss insertion point implementation slightly.